# Implementing barcode webcam reader jakobreiter quaggajs in Yii2

Tags: yii2, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement a webcam barcode reader to search in my grid but I don't understand how to implement it.

This is in the jakobreiter documentation but not sure the html markup i need to use to make it work.

```
echo YiiQuagga::widget([
    "id" => 'codereader',
    'name' => 'BarcodeForm[number]',
    'target' => '#barcodeform-number',
    'messages' => '#messages',
]);
```

Comment: you might have to look into the js plugin implementation first i dont think you are going to get any help from the repo owner as the last update was `on Jul 19, 2015`

Comment: moreover the widget `run()` function is creating a div that have the `data` attributes set to the `target`, `name` and `messages` respectively so if you can go through the js examples or dics you can have the idea about why it sets the `data` attributes of the `div` with the class `viewport`